# How create touch events for Overlays?

Tags: android, overlay

I add Overlays to my mapview and i want to events that occurs when touch to the overlays. I have used onTap but it is only for clicking to overlays.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `Overlay` and override `onTouchEvent()`. You can do any touch processing you desire there.